# Json data flattening on snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to flatten below Json data on snowflake :

Json Data :

```
 {
    "empDetails": [
        {
            "kind": "person",
            "fullName": "John Doe",
            "age": 22,
            "gender": "Male",
            "phoneNumber": {
                "areaCode": "206",
                "number": "1234567"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Jane",
                    "gender": "Female",
                    "age": "6"
                },
                {
                    "name": "John",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "age": "15"
                }
            ],
            "citiesLived": [
                {
                    "place": "Seattle",
                    "yearsLived": [
                        "1995"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "place": "Stockholm",
                    "yearsLived": [
                        "2005"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "kind": "person",
            "fullName": "Mike Jones",
            "age": 35,
            "gender": "Male",
            "phoneNumber": {
                "areaCode": "622",
                "number": "1567845"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Earl",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "age": "10"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Sam",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "age": "6"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Kit",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "age": "8"
                }
            ],
            "citiesLived": [
                {
                    "place": "Los Angeles",
                    "yearsLived": [
                        "1989",
                        "1993",
                        "1998",
                        "2002"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "place": "Washington DC",
                    "yearsLived": [
                        "1990",
                        "1993",
                        "1998",
                        "2008"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "place": "Portland",
                    "yearsLived": [
                        "1993",
                        "1998",
                        "2003",
                        "2005"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "place": "Austin",
                    "yearsLived": [
                        "1973",
                        "1998",
                        "2001",
                        "2005"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "kind": "person",
            "fullName": "Anna Karenina",
            "age": 45,
            "gender": "Female",
            "phoneNumber": {
                "areaCode": "425",
                "number": "1984783"
            },
            "citiesLived": [
                {
                    "place": "Stockholm",
                    "yearsLived": [
                        "1992",
                        "1998",
                        "2000",
                        "2010"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "place": "Russia",
                    "yearsLived": [
                        "1998",
                        "2001",
                        ""
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "place": "Austin",
                    "yearsLived": [
                        "1995",
                        "1999"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm able to flatten the most of the data except for column/array years Lived,
for last column I'm getting null values.

below is what I have tried so far :

```
  select empd.value:kind,
  empd.value:fullName,
  empd.value:age,
  empd.value:gender,   
  empd.value:phoneNumber,
  empd.value:phoneNumber.areaCode, 
  empd.value:phoneNumber.number ,
  empd.value:children, 
  chldrn.value:name,
  chldrn.value:gender,
  chldrn.value:age,
  city.value:place,
  yr.value:yearsLived
  from my_json emp,
  lateral flatten(input=>emp.Json_data:empDetails) empd , 
  lateral flatten(input=>empd.value:children, OUTER => TRUE) chldrn,   
  lateral flatten(input=>empd.value:citiesLived) city,
  lateral flatten(input=>city.value:yearsLived) yr -- not getting data for 
  this array
```

can someone help me understand why I'm getting null values for yearsLived array ? I'm not sure if I'm missing anything here

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the column

```
yr.value:yearsLived
```

as if `yr.value` were an OBJECT with fields.

But you have already expanded the `yearsLived` field in the line

```
lateral flatten(input=>city.value:yearsLived) yr
```

so `yr.value` is really just a `VARIANT` containing the year. You can leave it as such—or perhaps wrap it in `TO_NUMBER` or `TO_VARCHAR` to have a more precise type.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this out.

```
create or replace table json_tab as
select parse_json('{ "place": "Austin","yearsLived": [ "1995","1999"]}') as years
select years:yearsLived[0]::int from json_tab
```

Since your JSON data is an array, you need to access the elements via index if you would like to get specific values or use any array function to explode it.

[image: See the result here]

with flatten function

```
select years, v.value::string 
from json_tab, 
lateral flatten(input =>years:yearsLived ) v;
```

[image: with flatten function]

Comment: I'm able to flatten yearsLived separately . . . I'm looking for flattening years lived along with other elements and arrays